# Given $x>0,y>0$, AND $\frac{3}{2 x^2+3 xy}+\frac{5}{3 xy+4 y^2} =2$, So max{xy}?

Tags: substitution, maximum-likelihood, homogeneous-equation

> Given  $x>0;y>0$; if $\frac{3}{2 x^2+3 xy}+\frac{5}{3 xy+4 y^2} =2$, Find max{xy}?

Here is my try:

**Solution 1:**

$xy=t$,

$\frac{3}{2 x^2+3t}+\frac{5}{3t+4y^2} =2$

$y = \frac{t}{x}$

$\frac{3}{2 x^2+3t}+\frac{5}{3t+4(\frac{t}{x})^2} =2$

$f(x)=x^4(12t-10)+x^2(34t^2-24t)+(24t^3-12t^2)=0$

Is it possible to continue using my idea?

I know I can use another way to solve it:

**Solution 2:**

[image: Solution 2]

I tried to convert it to latex manually one letter by one letter and I can save some type operation with the help of this website:

https://www.simpletex.cn/ai/latex_ocr

Is there any better way to write it in latex?

I manually write it in the page within 6 minutes, but converting it to latex takes me over 20 minutes.

$$x y = x y \cdot \frac 1 2 ( \frac 3 { 2 x ^ 2+ 3 x y }+\frac5{3xy+4y^2})=\frac12(\frac{3y}{2x+3y}+\frac{5x}{3x+4y})$$

$$\begin{gathered}\begin{cases}2x+3y=m\\3x+8y=n\end{cases}\Rightarrow\begin{cases}6x+9y=3m\\6x+8y=2n\end{cases}\Rightarrow\begin{cases}x=3n-4m\\y=3m-2n\end{cases} \\xy=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{9m-6n}{m}+\frac{15n-20m}{n})=\frac{1}{2}(24-\frac{6n}{m}-\frac{20m}{n})
\end{gathered}$$

$$xy\le 12 - 2\sqrt{30}$$

Here is the reasoning:

easy to know:
$$m > 0$$
$$n > 0$$

$$x=3n-4m > 0$$

$$y=3m-2n > 0$$

$$
\frac{4}{3}m < n < \frac{3}{2}m
$$
i.e.
$$
1.33m < n < 1.5m
$$

m = 2x + 3y > 0

n = 3x + 4y > 0

When the following equation is real, it will get the min.

$\frac{6}{}=\frac{20}{}$

At that time,
$$
n = \frac{\sqrt{30}}{3}m = 1.82m
$$

does not fulfill the above:

$$
1.33m < n < 1.5m
$$

So it will not occur.

Update to the answer 1:

I type in "\frac {1}{6}\left(5- \frac{13z+24}{6Power[z,2]+17z+12}\right) max" into the  WolframAlpha. But it give me like the below

[image: WolframAlpha]

[image]

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Is it possible to continue the idea of solution 1.

Comment: I got the maximum of $xy$ to be $\dfrac{5}{6}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're given $x \gt 0, y \gt 0 $ and

$ \dfrac{3}{2 x^2 + 3 xy } + \dfrac{5}{3 xy + 4 y^2} = 2 $

Multiply through by the common denominator,

$ 3 (3 xy + 4 y^2) + 5 (2 x^2 + 3 xy) = 2 (2 x^2 + 3 xy) (3 x y + 4 y^2 ) $

From which,

$ 10 x^2 + 12 y^2 + 24 xy = 2 x y ( 2 x + 3 y)( 3 x + 4 y ) $

So that,

$  5 x^2 + 6 y^2 + 12 xy = x y ( 6 x^2 + 12 y^2 + 17 x y ) $

Now use polar coordinates, define

$ x= r \cos t$ , and $ y = r \sin t $ , where $ r \gt 0 $, then

the equation becomes

$ 5 \cos^2 t + 6 \sin^2 t + 12 \cos t \sin t \\
= r^2 \cos t \sin t (6 \cos^2 t + 12 \sin^2 t + 17 \cos t \sin t ) $

But $ x y = r^2 \cos t \sin t $ , therefore,

$ x y = \dfrac{ 5 \cos^2 t + 6 \sin^2 t + 12 \cos t \sin t }{6 \cos^2 t + 12 \sin^2 t + 17 \cos t \sin t} = \dfrac{ 5.5 - 0.5 \cos(2t) + 6 \sin(2t) }{9 - 3 \cos(2t) + 8.5 \sin(2 t) } $

Define the point in the $(U, V)$ plane as follows

$ U = 9 - 3 \cos(2t) + 8.5 \sin(2 t) $

$ V = 5.5 - 0.5 \cos(2t) + 6 \sin(2t) $

Note that $ 0 \lt t \lt \dfrac{\pi}{2} $

The point $(U,V)$ traces an ellipse in the $(U,V)$ plane, and that is plotted below.  From the plot, it is clear that the maximum ratio $\dfrac{V}{U}$ occurs at $U = 6 , V = 5$.  Therefore our maximum is $\dfrac{5}{6}$.

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150033/discussion-on-answer-by-hosam-h-given-x0-y0-and-frac32-x23-xy-frac); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Setting $z=\frac xy$ you can rearrange the given equation to
$$xy = \frac 16\left(5- \frac{13z+24}{6z^2+17z+12}\right)$$
So, there is **no maximum** but a **supremum** which is $\boxed{\frac 56}$.

**Addendum due to comments:**

We have $x,y > 0$. Hence,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{3}{2 x^2+3 xy}+\frac{5}{3 xy+4 y^2} & = & 2 \\
& \Leftrightarrow & \\
\frac 12\left(\frac{3}{2\frac xy +3}+\frac{5}{3+4\frac yx}\right) & = & xy  \\
& \stackrel{z=\frac xy > 0}{\Leftrightarrow} & \\
\frac 12\left(\frac{3}{2z +3}+\frac{5}{3+\frac 4z}\right) & = & xy  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, you rearrange the LHS and do a polynomial division:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac 12\left(\frac{3}{2z +3}+\frac{5}{3+\frac 4z}\right) 
& = & \frac{5z^2+12z+6}{6z^2+17z+12}  \\
& = & \frac 56 - \underbrace{\frac{\frac{13}6 z+4}{6z^2+17z+12}}_{q(z):= }  \\
& \stackrel{z>0}{<} & \frac 56
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that $\displaystyle \lim_{z\to\infty}q(z) = 0$.

Comment: I googled the terms supremum vs maximum. "A supremum is a number such that it is larger than all numbers in the given sequence. Although this is true for a maximum, the maximum has an additional property that it must be a member of the sequence so although each maximum is a supremum this is how they differ.
" I still do not understand it. Could you elaborate a little bit with this example?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit about why the solution 2 is wrong?

Comment: How do you come up with the final answer? Could you provide more detail?

Comment: @FrancisBacon I will add something to my answer. This is going to take some minutes.

Comment: Could you explain more about how to get the maximum of $\frac{5z^2+12z+6}{6z^2+17z+12}$? I still do not quite understand it.

Comment: @FrancisBacon
You need to be more specific in what you do not understand.
I transform the quotient into the form $\frac 56 - ...$ by a polynomial division. Since polynomial division is a standard procedure I won't write down all steps. You can use WolframAlpha to check the result.
And, btw., I show that there is a supremum but not a maximum.

Comment: If your result is correct, should we firstly prove that it is increasing function? But I do not see you prove that...so that may be puzzling to me. Do you use WolframAlpha to prove that? Sorry, I am not quite familiar with WolframAlpha but I will give it a try later.

Comment: How do you know it is an increasing function so quickly? Guess that derivative this function may take time, but you did not spend much time to conclude to that conclusion?

Comment: @FrancisBacon
Look carefully at the expression $q(z)$. For $z>0$ this quotient is obviously always positive. So, we subtract something positive from $\frac 56$. On the other hand, $q(z) \stackrel{z\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$. This means, with increasing $z$ we get arbitrary close to $\frac 56$ from below. No need to use monotonicity here.

Comment: @FrancisBacon I just saw your screenshots you added to your answer. Don't forget that $x,y>0 \Rightarrow z>0$. The local maximum indicated by WA refers to a negative $z$-value.

Comment: @transcelocation Yes, thanks, use "\frac {1}{6}\left(5- \frac{13z+24}{6Power[z,2]+17z+12}\right) max z > 0" give me the correct answer, WA is amazing, so you are!!!